# Delete of one record with 3mb data in Azure MS SQL table takes 10 seconds

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-delete

I have a table with 2 columns: bigint 'data_id' and nvarchar(max) 'data'. 'Data' field may contain around 1-3mb of text (it's json data. Project is moving from MySQL, that is why this is just a text field by now).

When I try to delete a record with a large 'data' field, it can take up to 7 seconds!

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[report_data_test2](
    [data_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [data] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_report_data_test2] ON [dbo].[report_data_test2] 
([data_id] ASC) 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

No foreign keys.

Table contains around 10k records. Sum of all 'data' fields is around 250mb. Database is Azure MS SQL (S2, 100 DTUs).

Here is the delete script

```
delete from [report_data_test] where data_id = 1414
```

It takes usually 5-7 seconds when performed on a record with 2-3mb 'data' field.

Execution plan shows that 'Table delete' takes 86% .

Do you have any advice how I can speed up the delete process?
Usually our application sends a request to delete up to 1000 records in one transaction. That is why I got a timeout at this step.

As the project is moving from MySQL now, I can do everything with this table, but I prefer to make as little efforts as possible to make the whole project work.

Thank you.

### Update.

Here is the result of running `select * from sys.dm_exec_requests` while the delete query is running.

```
session_id  106
request_id  0
start_time  42:41.3
status  suspended
command DELETE
sql_handle  0x02000000595C9328EB84FAA4B8E7631D196E98F2C3C9A7070000000000000000000000000000000000000000
statement_start_offset  26
statement_end_offset    116
plan_handle 0x06000500595C9328707BAB878B00000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
database_id 5
user_id 1
connection_id   B73B46C2-556B-40FF-898D-26F14CDA21C7
blocking_session_id 0
wait_type   LOG_RATE_GOVERNOR
wait_time   34
last_wait_type  LOG_RATE_GOVERNOR
wait_resource   
open_transaction_count  2
open_resultset_count    1
transaction_id  15007856
context_info    0x420037003300420034003600430032002D0035003500360042002D0034003000460046002D0038003900380044002D003200360046003100340043004400410032003100430037
percent_complete    0
estimated_completion_time   0
cpu_time    13
total_elapsed_time  2618
scheduler_id    0
task_address    0x98B12EDF5B039E25
reads   0
writes  808
logical_reads   3017
text_size   2147483647
language    us_english
date_format mdy
date_first  7
quoted_identifier   1
arithabort  1
ansi_null_dflt_on   1
ansi_defaults   0
ansi_warnings   1
ansi_padding    1
ansi_nulls  1
concat_null_yields_null 1
transaction_isolation_level 2
lock_timeout    -1
deadlock_priority   0
row_count   1
prev_error  0
nest_level  0
granted_query_memory    0
executing_managed_code  0
group_id    2000000026
query_hash  0xBBCA009F1B2E8872
query_plan_hash 0x0A6C949D252E8586
statement_sql_handle    0x0900EB84FAA4B8E7631D196E98F2C3C9A7070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
statement_context_id    10
dop 1
parallel_worker_count   NULL
external_script_request_id  NULL
```

Comment: run update statistics on table  and see ,if you are getting the same behaviour..if you are,then try to get wait stats when the query is running and update the question..

Comment: update statistics query:`update statistics tablename`

Comment: wait stats query to be ran ,once you fire delete:`select * from sys.dm_exec_requests where sessionid=sessionid of delete`

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thank you for your advice. I have updated the question. As far as I can see, the wait type is LOG_RATE_GOVERNOR. According [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269834.aspx) it occurs when DB is waiting for quota to write to the log. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Would it make sense to add an IsDeleted column to your table and stamp it to true when the row is deleted? You would obviously need to filter out rows where IsDeleted = 1 in other queries, but you could defer the physical deletion of the row to a background process, job, nightly, etc. I know this doesn't answer the question directly, but may be a decent strategy. :-)

Comment: @DanielG Than you for the idea. I have already implemented this approach a week ago when I couldn't find a solution. Cleaning job deletes a few records when the system is not not so busy. :)

Comment: Most excellent, Starina. I think this is a good long-term strategy for you, and probably even better than optimizing the transaction based approach.

Answer (score 0):

based on what you shared it seems that your entire workload hits Log IO limit of S2 tier. This can be due to this particular query or due to the fact that *all of your queries* generate more Log IO than S2 can effectively handle. However, you can double check that assumption. To get more details, I recommend you to use **Query Performance Insight** feature that is available on Azure portal (more details here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-query-performance/).
To get to QPI, open database blade on the portal and navigate to "SUPPORT + TROUBLESHOOTING" section. QPI will give you top N queries across different resource metrics (CPU, Data IO, Log IO), so you can conclude whether there are other queries that contribute overall Log IO.

In case you are really hitting Log IO limits while changing application logic or schema is not an option for you, you can increase service tier to get more Log IO bandwidth.